# preg_match for . / or \ in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match . \ or / using preg_match in PHP.

I thought this would do it but it's matching all strings.

```
$string = '';
$chars = '/(\.|\\|\/)/';
if (preg_match($chars, $string) != 0) {
    echo 'Chars found.';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you get some error?

Comment: Everything matches, not just strings with .\ or / in them. I don't get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument given to `preg_match()` is string. Strings are automatically escaped by PHP. For example, if you have `{\\\\}` (backslash) given to the regexp engine, PHP will first parse it creating `{\\}` (`\\` is replaced by `\`).

Next, regexp engine parses the regexp. It sees `{\\}` which PHP gave to regexp engine. It sees `\` as escape character, so it actually matches `\` character which was escaped by `\`.

In your case, it looks like `/(\.|\\|\/)/`. PHP gives to regexp engine `/(\.|\|\/)/` which is actually either `.` or `|/` (notice that `|` character was escaped).

Personally, I try to avoid escaping meta-characters, especially with how regexp engine works. I usually use `[.]` instead, it's more readable. Your regexp written with this would look like `/([.]|\\\\|[/])/`.

It's possible to do few optimizations. While it's my personal thing, I prefer to use `{}` as delimiters (yes, you can use pairs of characters). Also, your regexp matches single characters, so you could easily write it as `{[.\\\\/]}`, which is very readable in my opinion (notice four slashes, it's needed because both PHP and regexp engine parse backslashes).

Also, `preg_match()` returns number of matches. It will be always bigger than `0`, so you  can easily consider it to be boolean and avoid writting `== 0`. Instead, you can insert `!` before string to make it negative. But I think you accidentally reversed condition (it matches if it doesn't match). Valid code below:

```
$string = '';
$chars = '{[.\\\\/]}';
if (preg_match($chars, $string)) {
    echo 'Chars found.';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` logic is flawed. [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) will return the number of matches. Therefore, `== 0` means "no matches".

That said, [single quoted strings](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.syntax.single) don't expand escape sequences except `\'` and `\\`. You need to double your backslash escape for it to appear in the regex as expected. Change your code to:

```
$string = '';
$chars = '/(\.|\\\\|\/)/';
if (preg_match($chars, $string) != 0) {
    echo 'Chars found.';
}
```

Here's a test case:

```
$strings = array('', '.', '/', '\\', 'abc');
$pattern= '/(\.|\\\\|\/)/'

foreach($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string) > 0) {
        printf('String "%s" matched!', $string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I've updated my code. That was just a typo in my example. The problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably with PHP. When escaping something in a regex string, you also need to escape the backslashes you use to escape, or PHP will attempt to interpret it as a special character.

As that probably didn't make sense, have an example.

`$string = "\."` will make PHP attempt to escape the ., and fail. You instead need to change this to `$string = "\\\."`.

Comment: Not when using single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to REGEX match slashes, I would strongly suggest using a different separator character than '/'. It reduces the amount of escaping you need to do and makes it much more readable:

```
$chars = '%(\.|\\|/)%';
```

Comment: Good call but it's still matching everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$chars = '%(\.|\\\\|/)%'
```